# Sorting rows in pandas first by timestamp values and then by giving particular order to categorical values of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column "user" containing categorical values(a,b,c,d). I only care about the ordering of two categories in ascending order (a, d). So (a,b,c,d) and (a,c,b,d) both are fine for me.

**How to create the ordering is the first part of the question?**

Secondly I have another column which contains "timestamps". I want to order my rows first by "timestamps" and then for the rows with same timestamps I want to sort with the above ordering of categorical values.

Lets say my data frame looks like this.

```
+-----------+------+
| Timestamp | User |
+-----------+------+
|         1 | b    |
|         2 | d    |
|         1 | a    |
|         1 | c    |
|         1 | d    |
|         2 | a    |
|         2 | b    |
+-----------+------+
```

I want first this kind of sorting to happen

```
+-----------+------+
| Timestamp | User |
+-----------+------+
|         1 | b    |
|         1 | a    |
|         1 | c    |
|         1 | d    |
|         2 | d    |
|         2 | a    |
|         2 | b    |
+-----------+------+
```

Followed by the categorical ordering of "user"

```
+-----------+------+
| Timestamp | User |
+-----------+------+
|         1 | a    |
|         1 | b    |
|         1 | c    |
|         1 | d    |
|         2 | a    |
|         2 | b    |
|         2 | d    |
+-----------+------+
```

**OR**

```
+-----------+------+
| Timestamp | User |
+-----------+------+
|         1 | a    |
|         1 | c    |
|         1 | b    |
|         1 | d    |
|         2 | a    |
|         2 | b    |
|         2 | d    |
+-----------+------+
```

As you can see the "c" and "b"'s order do not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify order in ordered categorical by `categories` and then call [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['User'] = pd.Categorical(df['User'], ordered=True, categories=['a','b','c','d'])

df = df.sort_values(['Timestamp','User'])
print (df)
   Timestamp User
2          1    a
0          1    b
3          1    c
4          1    d
5          2    a
6          2    b
1          2    d
```

If there is many values of `User` is possible dynamically create categories:

```
vals = ['a', 'd']
cats = vals + np.setdiff1d(df['User'], vals).tolist() 
print (cats)
['a', 'd', 'b', 'c']

df['User'] = pd.Categorical(df['User'], ordered=True, categories=cats)
df = df.sort_values(['Timestamp','User'])
print (df)
   Timestamp User
2          1    a
4          1    d
0          1    b
3          1    c
5          2    a
1          2    d
6          2    b
```